# Get HTTP POST parameter order in Spring WebFlux application

Tags: http, spring-webflux

I have the following method setup in a @RestController annotated class to handle a POST request and get access to the POST parameters (application/x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
@PostMapping("/path")
fun postHandlingMethod(@RequestBody body: MultiValueMap<String,String>): Mono<String> {
  ...
}
```

For legacy system compatibility I need to know the order of the POST parameters in the request. This is of course not possible when using a Map.

Does anybody know a simple way to make all the POST parameters accessible together with the ordering information or will I have to write my own HttpMessageReader?

Comment: order by what...?

Comment: I am talking about the order the parameters appear in the request. E.g. when the body is

`foo=abc&bar=def`

I want to know that foo comes first and bar is the second parameter and so on.

Comment: Order is never guaranteed, you should never write code that is dependent on order, unless you sort the items yourself. So if you want order, you have to sort. What you are asking does not exist